# mkoctfile error when including octave header files

Tags: c++, fortran, octave, gfortran

If I want to compile Fortran files using the Octave header files (e.g. mex.h, mxarray.h,...) that include the c++ standard library I get errors like

> #include "error.h"
> 1~~~~~~~~
> Fatal Error: cstring: not found

So the c++ standard library is not found.

Comment: Do you have the C++ standard library installed?

Comment: Wait, what *exactly* are you doing? Please show a [mcve]. It is not even clear to me whether the file that includes include line is C++ or Fortran. Show a self-contained example and the *full* error output (if it is not huge as C++ template errors sometimes tend to be).